# Refresh HTML(JSP view) table after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I have an HTML table which is populated in my JSP view. This table always contains data of the default today date. The data is retrieved by an automatic batch that fetch data from a database. However i have to give a functionnality to be able to select data on a daterange. This is why I use a daterangepicker. I succeeded to apply to datefilter with ajax calls.

**What I want to do is to now when I select a new DateRange i update my already HTML table with the default date with Data from the selected date to replace the old data with new data in my table**

Here is my JSP page with the table i want to update when i Select **a DATERANGE**:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <table width="100%"class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tableUp">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>FormName</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Language</th>
                <th>Sent To NAS</th>
                <th>Sending Date</th>
                <th>FeedBack Received</th>
                <th>Feedback not Received</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id='tbod'>
            <tr class="odd gradeX" id="myTable">
                <c:forEach var="item" items="${eblinb2b_list}">
                    <tr id=1>
                        <td><c:out value="${item.form_name}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${item.mode}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${item.language}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${item.count}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${item.sendingDate}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**For the purpose of understanding a put here a new table in the lower part of my JSP view so that you understand:**

```
<!-- DateRange PICKER -->

<div class="panel-body">
    <table width="100%" class="class2" id="mainTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>FormName</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Language</th>
                <th>Sent To NAS</th>
                <th>Sending Date</th>
                <th>FeedBack Received</th>
                <th>Feedback not Received</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="odd gradeX" id="myTable1"></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="text" name="datepickerinput" id="datepicker" value="" />
</div>
<!-- /.panel-body -->
<button onclick="filterByDate()" id="button">Apply filter</button>
```

**Here is my JavaScript function part that populate my second table for illustrating**

```
**//Function for populating second table with Ajax JSON response**
var table = $("#mainTable tbody");
$.each(data, function(idx, elem) {
    var time = new Date(elem.sendingDate);
    var parsedTime = time.getDate() + "/" + (time.getMonth() + 1) + "/"
                                    + time.getFullYear();

    table.append("<tr><td>" + elem.form_name + "</td><td>"
                            + elem.mode + "</td><td>" + elem.language
                            + "</td><td>" + elem.count + "</td><td>"
                            + parsedTime + "</td></tr>");
```

Comment: My suggestion would be go with **[jQgrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)** or some other grid techniques, which serves your requirement better. All you need to do is import related JS files and create a mapping between json and table. Do let me know if you need any help in that.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I finally find the solution for my case. Check my answer

Comment: Glad that you were able to solve :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded to manage the problem this is my final function that updates the table by putting the data and replacing the old one:

```
                    function prepareTable(data) {

                    //Function for populating table with Ajax JSON response

                    var table = $("#tableUp #tbody1");
                    var html = "";
                    $.each(data, function(idx, elem) {

                        var time = new Date(elem.sendingDate);

                        var parsedTime = time.getDate() + "/"
                                + (time.getMonth() + 1) + "/"
                                + time.getFullYear();

                        html += "<tr><td>" + elem.form_name + "</td><td>"
                                + elem.mode + "</td><td>" + elem.language
                                + "</td><td>" + elem.count + "</td><td>"
                                + parsedTime + "</td><td></td><td></td></tr>";

                    });

                    table.html(html);

                }
```

**The prepareTable() function is triggered (called) when the Ajax call succeeded:**

```
                    function filterByDate() {

                    var startDate = document.getElementById("datepicker").value
                            .substring(0, 10);

                    var endDate = document.getElementById("datepicker").value
                            .substring(13, 23);

                    $.ajax({
                        url : '/gms/eblinb2b/filterOnDate',

                        data : {
                            "startDate" : startDate,
                            "endDate" : endDate
                        }, //here you send the daterange over an Ajax request and by default it's sended with a GET method
                        success : function(data) {

                            //here you will see displaying the callback result coming from your spring controller
                            console.log(data);

                            //Here we populate the HTML table with the new data based on the new daterange filter applied and replace the old data in my table
                            prepareTable(data);

                        },

                        error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            if (xhr.status == 404) {
                                alert(thrownError);
                            }
                        }

                    });
                }
```